# Split cells vertically on comma

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

This takes a field delimited by commas, and splits on the comma.  The newly divided information is put in another field (created at the start of the program) called `lob`.  Each part of the split is put in the `lob` field in a duplicate record of the original record from before the split.  The primary key is ID which is automatically generated.

Here is a concise example of desired behavior (many fields omitted for visual clarity):

Before running the module:

> ```
>  +--------------------------------------------+
>  |  ID   | App Code  |   Lines Of Business    |
>  +-------+-----------+------------------------+
>  |   1   |    AB23   | Value1, Value 2,Value3 |
>  +------ +-----------+------------------------+
>  |   2   |    XY45   |         Value 2        |
>  +--------------------------------------------+
> ```

After running the module:

> ```
>  +-------------------------------------------------------+
>  |  ID   | App Code  |   Lines Of Business    |   lob    |
>  +-------+-----------+------------------------+----------+
>  |   1   |    AB23   | Value1, Value 2,Value3 |  Value1  |
>  +-------+-----------+------------------------+----------+
>  |   2   |    XY45   |         Value 2        |  Value 2 |
>  +-------+-----------+------------------------+----------+ 
>  |   3   |    AB23   | Value1, Value 2,Value3 |  Value 2 |
>  +-------+-----------+------------------------+----------+
>  |   4   |    AB23   | Value1, Value 2,Value3 |  Value3  |
>  +-------------------------------------------------------+
> ```

Is there a way to accomplish this task in a more elegant or accurate way?  Efficiency is also good, but this program already runs quick enough on my data-set.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReformatTable()

    Dim db                       As DAO.Database
    Dim rs                       As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsADD                    As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld                      As DAO.Field

    Dim strSQL                   As String
    Dim varData                  As Variant
    Dim i                        As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb

    ' Add a field into the existing IIPM table called lob.
    ' Values created during the Line Of Business split will be stored here.
    Dim strDdl As String
    strDdl = "ALTER TABLE IIPM ADD COLUMN lob TEXT(255);"
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl

    ' Select all fields that have a Line of Business and are unprocessed (lob is Null)
    strSQL = "SELECT *, lob FROM IIPM WHERE ([Lines Of Business] Is Not Null) AND ([lob] Is Null)"

    Set rsADD = db.OpenRecordset("IIPM", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

    With rs
        While Not .EOF
            varData = Split(rs![Lines Of Business], ",") ' Get all comma delimited fields

            'Update First Record
            .Edit
            !lob = Trim(varData(0)) ' remove spaces before writing new fields
            .Update

            ' Add records with same first field
            ' and new fields for remaining data at end of string
            For i = 1 To UBound(varData)
                rsADD.AddNew
                For Each fld In rsADD.Fields
                    If fld.Name <> "lob" And fld.Name <> "ID" Then
                        ' Copy all fields except "lob" and "ID"
                        rsADD(fld.Name) = rs(fld.Name)
                    End If
                Next fld
                ' lob is set separately, ID is set automatically
                rsADD!lob = Trim(varData(i)) ' remove spaces before writing new fields
                rsADD.Update
            Next i

            .MoveNext
        Wend

        .Close
        rsADD.Close

    End With

    Set rsADD = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

    ' Remove empty rows which only contain an ID.
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "DELETE FROM IIPM WHERE lob IS NULL AND [App Code] IS NULL AND [Lines Of Business] IS NULL;"

    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not put the results in the same table.  I would make a new table and put the results in the new table.  The new table can use the same surrogate keys as the original.  It is a basic principle in database design that you never work on live data when doing development.  I also like inputs and outputs to be separate.  Sometimes you can damage the data subtly and if you have changed the input data rather than create a separate output table, these changes can be harder to detect and remedy.

Other than that the code looks fine.

Comment: Can you explain why it would be better to put the results in a new table. This may be helpful to the person asking the question and others.